# FxCop Rule to check for constraints on MVC Routes

Tags: model-view-controller, code-analysis, fxcop

My company has implemented a policy that all routes must have constraints, and I was wondering if anyone knows of a custom rule for FxCop (1.36) that will check the routes and flag any without constraints, or if it's even possible to do with FxCop.

Answer (score 1):

I am unaware of any custom FxCop rules that check for route constraints.  However, it's quite feasible to create such a rule if you only wish to check routes configured directly in code (as opposed to loaded from some other source like a config file).  If you're unable or unwilling to tackle this yourself, you might want to try requesting the rule at http://fxcopaspnetsecurity.codeplex.com/.